# How to zoom in on Calendar?

Tags: macos, big-sur, calendar

How can I show fewer or more hours at a time in Week view in Calendar.app without opening preferences every time?

Pinching does nothing for me, heightening or shortening the window just proportionally grows/shrinks the vertical size of each hour too so the same number of hours are shown no matter the window size.

Comment: Did my Alternate Solution work for you?

Answer (score 4):

My guess would be that by default with having the, e.g. **Show: [12] hours at a time** *preference* in **Calendar** > **Preferences…** > **General**, that will be the only way to change the number of hours shown from within **Calendar**, regardless of the size of the *window*. I tested with various combinations of *modifier keys* and it didn't help to change the number of hours displayed.

That said, I did test doing it programmatically thru scripting and assigning a *keyboard shortcut* to an **Automator** *Quick Action/Service* and it does work.

---

### Alternate Solution

Create two **Automator** *Quick Action/Service*, with settings:

- **Workflow receives [no input] in [Calendar]**

Add a **Run Shell Script** *action* to each, with settings:

- **Shell: [/bin/zsh]**
- **Pass input: [to stdin]**

Add the following *example* **shell script** *code* to the first one and save it as, e.g.:

- **Zoom out Hours in Calendar**

*Example* **shell script** *code*:

```zsh
deltaHours=2
currentHours=$(defaults read com.apple.iCal 'number of hours displayed')
[ $((currentHours + deltaHours)) -gt 24 ] && exit 0
defaults write com.apple.iCal 'number of hours displayed' -int $((currentHours + deltaHours))
```

Add the following *example* **shell script** *code* to the second one and save it as, e.g.:

- **Zoom in Hours in Calendar**

*Example* **shell script** *code*:

```zsh
deltaHours=2
currentHours=$(defaults read com.apple.iCal 'number of hours displayed')
[ $((currentHours - deltaHours)) -lt 6 ] && exit 0
defaults write com.apple.iCal 'number of hours displayed' -int $((currentHours - deltaHours))
```

**Notes:**

In **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** I assigned each a *keyboard shortcut* of **⌘K** and **⌥⌘K** respectively.

In testing, I could press the assigned *keyboard shortcut* multiple time in a row quickly and have the number of hours displayed increase/decrease.

The *example* **shell script** *code* as currently coded  will increase/decrease by two hours with each pressing of the assigned *keyboard shortcut*.

The *example* **shell script** *code*, shown above, was tested in a **Run Shell Script** *action* as an **Automator** *Quick Action/Service* with *keyboard shortcuts* assigned under **macOS Catalina** and **macOS Big Sur** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **shell script** *code* is just that, an example, and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed, or wanted. The onus in upon the user to ensure the *script* is fit for use for ones purpose.</sub>

Comment: This didn’t work anymore in macOS Sonoma 14.0. Took me about an hour to find that simply by replacing ```com.apple.iCal``` by ```/Users/[username]/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iCal.plist``` did the trick. Thanks!